# Pure lightbox inside jquery EasyTabs

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm trying to use the lightbox built into "Pure," though this same problem will likely occur with any lightbox, inside of the jQuery EasyTabs plugin. It works in the active tab, but not when inside any inactive tabs - likely due to the size being collapsed until the tab is activated.

EasyTabs has a feature built-in to trigger events after a tab has been selected:

```
$('.fluidbox.fluidOn').bind('easytabs:after' function() {

});
```

However, after trying several different events I've hit a stump, can't seem to bind the right function inside for it to trigger correctly.

Here's a link to a [live example](http://onelittledesigner.com/testing/johnny/).

The B&W ones will work as they're initialized on load, but then go to the 2nd tab Cityscape and it fails to load, though the script is properly wrapping the images for the lightbox (.fluidbox-wrap).

Not sure this will help, but I was able to resolve this issue for Google Maps [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/G7keE/8/). You'll see the bind event on line 579:

```
$('#tab-container').bind('easytabs:after', function() {
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');     
});
```

I've been trying similar resizing attempts on the images but nothings been working for me. I feel I'm missing something very simple - just hitting one of those annoying stumps >:(

**Edit**

The lightbox I'm using is called Fluid Box, though I'm fairly certain the issue is triggering inside EasyTabs and nothing to do with Fluid Box in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, much easier fix than I thought it was going to be.

I had easyTabs loading as (document).ready and simply switching to (window).load allowed Fluid Box to fully load.